# Why does Handler.Post Block the main Thread

Tags: android

This is a class which extends Thread and implements the run() function:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread{
public Handler handler;
public TestThread(){

    handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
}
public Looper getLooper(){
    return Looper.myLooper();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Looper.prepare();
        Looper.loop();      
}
}
```

Now in a button in the main activity I have this code:

```
TestThread t=new TestThread();
    t.start();  
    Handler h=new Handler(t.getLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true);
        }
    });
```

As far as I know this is supposed to put the runnable in the target Thread's message queue and the thread (not UI thread) will run it when possible.
But this code blocks the UI. why does this happen? As you see I sent the target thread's looper to the Handler constructor and the handler should use that looper not the main thread's looper.

Comment: t.getLooper() returns UI Looper,  why don't you use a HandlerThread class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Looper.myLooper()` returns the current thread looper which is the calling UI thread's looper for you. Then you make a handler with it and post a blocking runnable there.

To make this "work", move the `myLooper()` call under the thread `run()` method.

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is a good answer. But I noticed there is another way. That if I init handler in the run() function and return it ,instead of returning the looper, I can use it(the handler) to post runnables to the target thread's looper. Because the handler has the thread's looper attached to it. But as you pointed this is necessary to do this inside the body of run. Because this part is actually related to the new thread.